# Is it bad to "catch" exceptions if all you do is print it to error?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Just a quick little question about coding in general.

Say you're using a try-catch block, but all you do with the exception is print it to stderr. In this case, are you better off simply letting the error happen and letting it print on its own? Or is it still better to catch the exception so that it is documented for other coders?

In languages like Java, there is a "throws exception", but as far as I can tell Python has nothing of that kind.

Thanks

Comment: That depends entirely on what code you're catching an error from, and how data from the `try` is used; among other things. If the failure in the `try` leaves your program in a bad state (like a variable never being set), that would certainly be bad, since then you'll just get a `NameError` right after when you try to use the data.

Comment: `try-catch` suppresses the error. If let the error happen your program will until the error the code block after encountering an error is not run. If you suppress the error with `try-catch` you run the code below. Read more about [`Errors, Exceptions and Handling`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions) from python docs

Comment: [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late) has some good discussion. But the general idea is that if you catch an exception, can you rectify whatever the issue was? If not, can you get your program back into a reasonable state? If it is truly fatal, then cleanup and end the program.

Comment: In python you can `raise` exception, just like you throw exception in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If we don't catch exception, then the normal flow of control will break where the exception occurred and will jump to the point where the exception is caught or the program will just terminate after printing the exception.

Not catching exception might be ok for simple programs, but for complex applications where we have multiple methods and libraries, we would wish to catch the exception where in the part of the program where it occurs and handle it according to our need. In web applications we may handle the exception and display user understandable error message.

In general, its always better to handle the exception even if we just print it to the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I would always **handle** and **catch** the **exception**. No matter, whether small or large project. Because by catching an exception, you can give the user precise information WHAT he e.g. entered incorrectly (too small / too large a number ...) So the entire program code does not always have to be run through, but it left at the point where the exception is thrown.

In python you can throw like in java (throw exception) but with `raise exception`.

Here a small, understanding [introduce for python exception](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/). So I learned the exception in python. Good luck!